# Count matching records from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables. "question_answers" having columns `question` and `answer`.
    "question_attempts" having `questionid` and `responsesummary`.

Example : `question`=4 having 5 records from "question_answers".
Same `questionid` in the "question_attempts" and find and get the count of matching records count in "question_attempts"

"question_answers"[image]
"question_attempts"[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? you should be able to (inner) join both tables and count

Comment: didn't use inner join. 
echo $data = mysql_num_rows("Select count(`responsesummary`) from `question_attempts` where `questionid`=4 AND `responsesummary`=43152");

This is the code i wrote. It is displaying in phpmyadmin,

Comment: But, not displaying while try to display in the page.

Comment: Give it a try, if didn't copy some queries here to generate your tables with some sample data. then other users (including myself) can try to write what you are seeking for you faster :)

Comment: you are mixing the **mysql_num_rows** method and **count** clause, the result _($data)_ always will be one. p.s. its not advised to use mysql_* methods anymore anyway :)

Comment: hhmm.
Could you please give me the solution!

Comment: can you clear more what do you want?? I m little confused

Comment: Okay.
Two tables are there right?
In "question_answers" table `question`=1 having 4 options right?
Take fist option "The element will be set to 0".
Now come to "question_attempts" table
And find `questionid`=1 and `responsesummary`='The element will be set to 0'.
And now count the number of 'The element will be set to 0.' record

Comment: Hi, Why i'm trying to ask question stackoverflow, it is giving "You have reached your question limit" Is this possible to remove my earlier questions and ask new question? If yes, please guide me. Thanks in Advance

Comment: How to get all the records of current logged in user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much easier if i could have a sample of those tables here, but give this a try

```sql
SELECT 
    answers.id AS 'answer id',
    count(attempts.id) AS 'number of attempts'    
FROM
    question_attempts AS attempts
JOIN
    question_answers AS answers ON answers.answer = attempts.responsessummary
WHERE 
    question_answers.question = 1
GROUP BY 
    answers.id;
```

if it works correctly you should receive a table of answer ids with the number of attempts for that answer.

**BUT** you need to have exact match in those two fields. answer from question_attempts and responsessummary from question_answers.

if it not possible the workaround is to use **LIKE** clause :

```sql
SELECT 
    answers.id AS 'answer id',
    count(attempts.id) AS 'number of attempts'    
FROM
    question_attempts AS attempts
JOIN
    question_answers AS answers ON answers.answer 
        LIKE CONCAT('%', attempts.responsessummary , '%')
WHERE 
    question_answers.question = 1
GROUP BY 
    answers.id;
```

Comment: Nothing displaying.
could you please guide me how to send files through this, i will send you those two tables please.

Comment: or else, give me the example with question=1

Comment: no need to send file , i think you should be able to copy your create query for both tables as well as some insert queries to add some data in each table.  if you need to add more filter just add a **WHERE** clause just before "GROUP BY" e.g. `WHERE question_answers.question = 1`

Comment: i really didn't understand.
Please give me the query using question=1
It's great helpful to me.

Comment: I've put that line in my answer (both queries) . But I'm afraid without queries to build your sample tables here i wont be any help

Comment: How to get all the records of current logged in user?

Comment: to do that you need to have a field addressing username or id (depend on your design) in your tables, then all you need to do is to add more conditions to your WHERE clause e.g. changing `question_answers.question = 1` to `question_answers.question = 1 AND question_answers.username = 'TheUserName'`